# Setting up Spek test for http methods using Kotlin?

Tags: testing, kotlin, http-method, ratpack, spek

How do I spin up a spek test using kotlin to test whether or not an HTTP method post has been called? Whats tripping me out is i'm having trouble mocking up the context. I'd like to pass in a method other then HttpMethod.POST to fire off the else block.

Currently fails with the message -

```
    handlers.AHandlerTest > initializationError FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
    Cannot mock/spy class ...handlers.AHandler
    Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
     - final class
        at handlers.AHandlerTest$1.invoke(AHandlerTest.kt:76)
        at handlers.AHandlerTest$1.invoke(AHandlerTest.kt:17)
```

It also fails saying context.request can't be null

```
import ratpack.handling.Context

class AHandler : Handler {

 override fun handle(contex: Context) {
        when (contex.request.method) {
            HttpMethod.POST -> create(contex)
            else -> {
                contex.response.status(405)
                contex.render("Unsupported method. Supported methods are: POST")
            }
        }
 }
}
```

test file:

```
package handlers

import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.doReturn
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.verify
import handlers.AHandler
import org.spekframework.spek2.Spek
import org.spekframework.spek2.style.specification.describe
import ratpack.handling.Context

import org.mockito.Mockito
import ratpack.http.HttpMethod
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.assertFails


class AHandlerTest: Spek({


    val context = mock<Context>()

    val httpReq = mock<Context> {
        on { context.request.method }.doReturn(HttpMethod.DELETE)
    }


    describe("testing handler function") {
        it("it should fail when not given a post method") {


        }
    }
})
```

Comment: When you mock `context`, do you specify what its `request` returns?

Comment: currently mocking context like this - val context = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java);

Comment: I am mocking the kind of http request i want returned i believe with this: 

val httpReq = mock<Context> {
        on { context.request.method }.doReturn(HttpMethod.DELETE)
    }

Comment: Your `AHandler` is final, so you can't mock it. Also, it looks like you are testing `AHandler`, so you shouldn't mock it.

Answer (score 0):

here's what helped me get it to pass -

```
describe("testing handle function") {
  it("it should fail when not given a post method") {
            val aHandler = AHandler();
            val result = RequestFixture.handle(aHandler, Action {request ->
                request.method("DELETE")
            })
            result.status.code shouldEqual 405

        }
    }
```

it passed the test after this